# loop for pearson correlation in r

Tags: r

```
res <- cor.test(my_data$G.1, my_data$G.2, method = "pearson")
if(res$estimate < 0.05) {
    my_data <- my_data[,-2]
}
```

How to write a pearson correlation for the first column verses the rest of the columns in R? We had written the code for comparing `G.1` vs `G.2`.

Comment: why do you have a python tag in there?

Comment: check out the r package `psych` . It has a correlation every against every variable feature also including testing.

Comment: You can use function `cor` instead of `cor.test` and pass not only vector, but full matrix or data.frame. So you can pass single column as one argument and the rest of the data.frame as the second argument.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, PoGibas. I am new to R. Please can you write the sample R code for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I send you an example with the base mtcars I hope it serves you

```
data("mtcars")
my_data <- mtcars[, c(1,3,4,5,6,7)]
```

If you do not want to obtain the correlation matrix but only the first column versus the rest

```
cor(my_data)[-1,1]
      disp         hp       drat         wt       qsec 
-0.8475514 -0.7761684  0.6811719 -0.8676594  0.4186840
```

Now if what you want to get is the p value of the `cor.test`, you can create this loop

```
rho <- pval <- NULL
for(i in 2:ncol(my_data)){
   rho[i-1]  <- cor.test(my_data[,1],my_data[,i], method = "pearson")$estimate
   pval[i-1] <- cor.test(my_data[,1],my_data[,i], method = "pearson")$p.value
 }
res <- cbind(rho,pval)
rownames(res) <- paste(colnames(my_data)[1],"vs",colnames(my_data)[2:ncol(my_data)])
res
                   rho         pval
mpg vs disp -0.8475514 9.380327e-10
mpg vs hp   -0.7761684 1.787835e-07
mpg vs drat  0.6811719 1.776240e-05
mpg vs wt   -0.8676594 1.293959e-10
mpg vs qsec  0.4186840 1.708199e-02
```

Comment: for(i in 2:ncol(my_data)){
  rho[i-1]  <- cor.test(my_data[,1],my_data[,i], method = "pearson")$estimate
  pval[i-1] <- cor.test(my_data[,1],my_data[,i], method = "pearson")$p.value
}
res <- cbind(rho,pval)
rownames(res) <- paste(colnames(my_data)[1],"vs",colnames(my_data)[2:ncol(my_data)])
i tried this code but i get the following error.     1.Error in cor.test.default(my_data[, 1], my_data[, i], method = "pearson") : 
  'y' must be a numeric vector  2.Error in `rownames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("X1 vs X2", "X1 vs X3", "X1 vs X4",  : 
  length of 'dimnames' [1]not equal to array extent